# Excel file corrupted after uploading to Sharepoint with Python

Tags: rest, excel, file-upload

Similar to [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6349de4a-d443-494d-8e63-194d7fc15a2f/excel-file-corrupted-after-uploading-to-sharepoint-with-python?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy) I'm having trouble opening a file uploaded via Python onto SharePoint. This is the code I'm using to upload the file:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\username','password', session)

files = {'file': ('_test.xlsx', open('_test.xlsx','rb'),
         'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
         {'Expires': '0'})
        }

put_url = 'https://secure.sp.kp.org/teams/scpmgcc/complete%20care/Proactive%20Care/POE_CCTE_TAT/2017%20Reports'
myFile = requests.put('{}/_test.xlsx'.format(put_url), 
                      files=files, 
                      auth=session.auth)
```

The error message is below:

[image]

Is SharePoint doing anything to the upload? Should I be encoding the data somehow? Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: I cannot make a comment, so I ask about the answer here! The answer which is marked as solution does not work for me. It does not give me any error, but no file is uploaded to the website!
What should I do? btw, what does the "header" do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the problem with my original code:
needed to provide `data` kwarg and NOT `files` kwarg:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\username','password', session)

put_url = 'https://secure.sp.kp.org/teams/scpmgcc/complete%20care/Proactive%20Care/POE_CCTE_TAT/2017%20Reports'
with open('p:/ccte/_ccte_tat_template.xls','rb') as fin:
    myFile = requests.put('{}/_ccte_tat_template.xls'.format(put_url), 
                          data=fin.read(), 
                          auth=session.auth, 
                          headers={'content-type':'application/vnd.ms-excel'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this using `urllib2`:

```
import os, urllib2

from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

base_url = "https://secure.sp.kp.org"
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, base_url, 'DOMAIN\\username', 'password')
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
filepath = 'p:/ccte/_ccte_tat_template.xls'
dirname, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
put_url = '{}/teams/scpmgcc/complete%20care/Proactive%20Care/POE_CCTE_TAT/2017%20Reports/{}'.format(base_url,filename)
with open(filepath,'rb') as fin:
  request = urllib2.Request(put_url,data=fin.read())

request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
url = opener.open(request)
```