# Excel file is not checked in after uploading to Sharepoint with Python

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, python

I have taken the following code from other post. This is very good and working fine.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\username','password', session)

put_url = 'https://secure.sp.kp.org/teams/scpmgcc/complete%20care/Proactive%20Care/POE_CCTE_TAT/2017%20Reports'
with open('p:/ccte/_ccte_tat_template.xls','rb') as fin:
    myFile = requests.put('{}/_ccte_tat_template.xls'.format(put_url), 
                          data=fin.read(), 
                          auth=session.auth, 
                          headers={'content-type':'application/vnd.ms-excel'})
```

The file is uploaded fine with checked out status. Please let me know how we can check in the file when uploading using the same above code.

I tried with different options :

```
my_headers = {
            'accept' : 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type' : 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'odata' : 'verbose',
            'X-RequestForceAuthentication' : 'true'
        }
```

Tried like below as well.

```
 import requests
    from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\username','password', session)

  my_headers = {
                'accept' : 'application/vnd.ms-excel;odata=verbose',
                'content-type' : 'application/vnd.ms-excel;odata=verbose',
                'odata' : 'verbose',
                'X-RequestForceAuthentication' : 'true',
                'Connection': 'close'
            }


    put_url = 'https://secure.sp.kp.org/teams/scpmgcc/complete%20care/Proactive%20Care/POE_CCTE_TAT/2017%20Reports'
    with open('p:/ccte/_ccte_tat_template.xls','rb') as fin:
        myFile = requests.put('{}/_ccte_tat_template.xls'.format(put_url), 
                              data=fin.read(), 
                              auth=session.auth, 
                              headers=my_headers)
```

Nothing is working. Any one has any idea how to fix this issue

Comment: First part of the code has taken from : Excel file corrupted after uploading to Sharepoint with Python     https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212803/excel-file-corrupted-after-uploading-to-sharepoint-with-python/276591?noredirect=1#comment294301_276591

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, you can go to **Library Settings -> Versioning Settings** and turn off **Require documents to be checked out before editing**, after which new files uploaded will not be checked out by default.

If that's not an option, I don't know python, but the general format for a REST call to check in a file looks like this:

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/{file_name}')/CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"
```

Ref: [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Comment: Thanks Joe.I know the first option. If we disable that checkout requirements will be turned off for existing files as well. For The second one getting 404 error.